# Translate html magento 2

Tags: magento2, translate

I am developing my custom module. I have the html template look like this

```
<p>
  This is a <strong>text that I need to translate</strong>
</p>
<p>Read more: <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">google.com</a></p>
```

How can I translate these nested texts? I know how to use i18n to translate but I don't know how to translate the text in `<p>` tag that has `<strong>` tag in the middle

I used this but not work

```
  <p >{{trans "This is a"}} <strong>{{trans "text that I need to translate."}}</strong></p>
```

I can do this and it works but I really don't like the extra span tag

```
 <p ><span data-bind="i18n: 'This is a '"/><strong data-bind="i18n: 'text that I need to translate.'"/></p>
```

**NOTE**: My file is the js component template so it's HTML. It is not phtml file

Comment: {{trans "A nice quote"}} and you might need a translation csv in your theme or something, this in email templates for example, in code you can try the function __('A nice quote'), I'm not good in defining translations myself but hope it helps or lead to something :D

Comment: Any tutorials/blogs/...that you recommend?

Comment: What do you want to translate? Text in email templates? In code? Translate the whole website to another language?

Comment: That's the text in my custom module. I know how to use i18n to translate but I don't know how to translate the text in <p> tag that has strong tag in the middle

Comment: Try to use __() instead of the {{trans }} might be easier

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

first create a custom module using this link https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Now create Below directory

**Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv**

Now in open en_US.csv in notepad and translate like below example

```
"Position","Featured"
```

here am changing Position with Featured

that's it you are done

Comment: Hi, I updated my question